# How do I use Nodejs OracleDB driver to do bulk inserts?

Tags: node.js, oracle

I have an array of objects that gets generated through a NodeJS stream. The array size varies dynamically based on the input. The maximum size of the array is 256. I do not want to insert into oracle DB for each record. Is there any way to insert all 256 record into Oracle using the NodeJS OracleDB driver?

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9526345800346872047 ? Also you can create temporary table, import data to it, bulk append to target, truncate temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current (as of [node-oracledb 1.10](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb)) has this array binding capability which can be useful.  See the [doc](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#plsqlindexbybinds):

> Arrays of strings and numbers can be bound to PL/SQL IN, IN OUT, and
>   OUT parameters of PL/SQL INDEX BY associative array type.

However from your description this may not suit.

A number of people find the [simple-oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-oracledb) wrapper on top of node-oracledb  meets their business/legal/security/performance needs.  It has some batch capabilities.